# Does a melded creature remain melded when it leaves the battlefield?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-meld

If a melded creature like [Brisela, Voice of Nightmares](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bBrisela%2c%20Voice%20of%20Nightmares%5d) dies, does it go to the graveyard as a single, melded creature, or does it split apart?

Can the whole creature be brought back to the battlefield (or to my hand), or just 1 of the 2 parts?

Do both halves of Brisela have to be regenerated separately?

Comment: "Resurrected" in what sense? Are you talking about [regenerating](http://magiccards.info/m15/en/168.html) the creature (while it's still on the battlefield), or effects that bring it from the graveyard to the battlefield, or something else?

Comment: Just to be clear, there's no mechanic called "resurrecting" -- but it is a slang term for a batch of effects that effectively put creatures from the graveyard on the battlefield. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, sorry. Sorta new to the game. Regeneration.  From graveyard to battle field, first of all- secondly from graveyard to hand. Just need to know whether or not those 2 parts of the oversize card creature will have to be regenerated seperately, or if they were sent to the graveyard as a single creature, if that means they can be brought back as the same creature.

Comment: A Melded Creature can only be a creature (and thus a Melded Creature) when it is on the battlefield. Anywhere else (graveyard, exile, hand, etc.) they are just separate creature cards.

Comment: Regeneration is expressly *not* an effect that returns anything from the graveyard to the battlefield. Regeneration in fact prevents it from going to the graveyard in the first place. See the description of it on [Ancient Silverback](http://magiccards.info/m15/en/168.html) for example. So do you mean regeneration, or returning from graveyard to hand/battlefield?

Comment: I think the section in the [Eldritch Moon release notes](http://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/feature/eldritch-moon-release-notes-2016-07-08) on meld might help you out a lot, whatever specific questions you may have.

Comment: @KevinDublanko Welcome to the site! The best way to respond to requests for clarification is to edit your post. I went ahead and edited yours to include the information you provided in the comments. In your case this means that the post now contains two unrelated questions: one about melded creatures dying, and another one about regenerating a melded creature. In general, you want to keep your questions separate, but in this case I think it's okay because you are not aware that your questions are unrelated.

Comment: My understanding of the comment was that the OP was accidentally using "regeneration" to refer to returning from graveyard to battlefield or hand, not realizing it was actually a term with specific meaning.

Comment: @Jefromi that might be the case; it's probably best handling both of them I guess

Answer (score 6):

From the [Eldritch Moon release notes](http://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/feature/eldritch-moon-release-notes-2016-07-08):

> While a meld card is anywhere other than the battlefield ... it has only the characteristics of its front face.

So once a melded creature is in the graveyard, the two parts have their front-face identities only and do not "remember" that they had been melded. Anything trying to move the cards back to hand or battlefield will have to interact with them separately.

However, a creature that is rescued from death with **regeneration** never actually leaves the battlefield at all, so regeneration works just fine on a melded creature. Regeneration does *not* mean to return the creature from the graveyard to the battlefield - rather it (roughly) means "the next time this creature would die, instead it doesn't."

Here's part of the [Comprehensive Rules](http://media.wizards.com/images/magic/tcg/resources/rules/MagicCompRules_21031101.pdf) on regenerate:

> 701.12a If the effect of a resolving spell or ability regenerates a permanent, it creates a replacement
>   effect that protects the permanent the next time it would be destroyed this turn. In this case, 
>   “Regenerate [permanent]” means “The next time [permanent] would be destroyed this turn,
>   instead remove all damage marked on it and tap it. If it’s an attacking or blocking creature,
>   remove it from combat.”

While the melded creature is on the battlefield it counts as just one creature, so a single regeneration effect can save it (you don't have to regenerate both halves).